# How to control the salesforce standard "sharing" button visibility for certain profiles or permission sets?

Tags: sharing

Salresforce standard "Sharing" button is added to all opportunity page layouts, however we would like to control the visibility of the button based on profiles . Could you please let me know whether there is any profile or permission set permission which controls the "sharing" button visibility . If not how to control the visibility of the button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to control this button would be with multiple page layouts, which you can then assign by profile. You cannot use Permission Sets to enable this button. Note that the Sharing button is also controlled by record access. The user can't grant more access to the record than they themselves have.

Comment: ok, could you please let me know whether it is possible to grant access to related custom object records as well . For e.g, if I share opportunity via sharing button, is there any way to share the associated related records as well  . Example : If I share opportunity via sharing button, can related quote records also be shared by means of any configuration or custom logic ?

Comment: Please let me know on above

Comment: @HemantKumarreddy If I recall correctly, the quote should automatically be shared when you share the opportunity. Different objects have different rules.

Comment: ok, is it possible to make other custom object records be shared automatically ? E.g : If we share opportunity via sharing button, is it possible to share associated custom object1 records which has a relationship to opportunity . If it is possible, could you please share how to implement it via config or custom code ? Thank you for your help

Comment: @HemantKumarreddy If it's a master-detail relationship, sharing is automatic. If it's just a lookup, no configuration or code will be possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward to today, there is now the feature of **Dynamic Actions on the Flexipage**

> With dynamic actions, you can add flexibility and control to actions on your record pages. Assign dynamic actions in the Lightning App Builder instead of in the page layout editor, and then apply filters to control when and where actions are visible to users.

So no longer multiple page layouts needed

More info : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_create_dynamic_action.htm&type=5